# Ansible | Set_fact with condition

Tags: ansible

I have the list:

```
val_list:
    - val: "D"
    - val: "A"
    - val: "B"
    - val: "C"
```

I would like to set variable true if list contain `val: B` without creating register variable task, for example:

```
- set_fact:
    containB: false

- set_fact:
    containB: true
  when: item.val=='B'
  with_items
    - "{{ val_list }}"
```

I would like to convert to something like that:

```
- set_fact: 
    containB: true if item.val=='B' | default(false)
#or containB: true if any val in val_list is 'B'
  with_items
    - "{{ val_list }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. extract values from the list with the `map` filter
2. check that 'B' is an element of the resulting list

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    val_list:
      - val: "D"
      - val: "A"
      - val: "B"
      - val: "C"

    list_contains_B: "{{ 'B' in (val_list | map(attribute='val')) }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Does list contain B ?
      debug:
        var: list_contains_B
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Does list contain B ?] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list_contains_B": true
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `in` operator to check if a list contains a value.
For example:

```
- set_fact:
    list_contains_b: "{{ {'val': 'B'} in val_list }}"
```

As a runnable playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    val_list:
      - val: "D"
      - val: "A"
      - val: "B"
      - val: "C"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list_contains_b: "{{ {'val': 'B'} in val_list }}"

    - debug:
        var: list_contains_b
```